# Setter Dependency Injection with Array of String

Tags: spring

To test the setter dependency injection with an Array of string, I wrote the below-given code -

**Pojo class is -**

```
package com.abhishek.ioc.array;

public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String[] hobbies;

    public void showHobbies() {
        System.out.println("Person name is - "+name+", id is - "+id);
        for (int i = 0; i < hobbies.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(hobbies[i]);
        }

    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setHobbies(String[] hobbies) {
        this.hobbies = hobbies;
    }
}
```

**spring.xml file is -**

```
<beans>
    <bean id="person" class="com.abhishek.ioc.array.Person">
        <property name="id" value="1"></property>
        <property name="name" value="Abhisshek"></property>
        <property name="hobbies">
            <set>
                <value>Playing cricket</value>
                <value>Coding</value>
                <value>Reading books</value>
            </set>

        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Client code is -**

```
package com.abhishek.ioc.array; 
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/spring.xml");  
        System.out.println("Creating Person object");
        Person person = (Person)applicationContext.getBean("person");
        System.out.println("Person object created");
        person.showHobbies();

    }
}
```

In spring.xml file, I tried tags `<array>, <list> and <set>` to inject data in array and all three tags are giving the correct result. How?